# Linq Join on Lists produces a list of duplicate data

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-2.0

Hi I have a puzzling issue(to me at leaast).

I am using the latest Entity Framework on NetCore 2

So I created these 2 lists like this:

```
var cYear = await _context.CYear
    .Where(c => c.Discriminator == 'C').ToListAsync();

var modCurricula = await _context.ModCurricula
    .Where(m => m.ProductionStatus == 1.ToListAsync();
```

Stepping through the code, I can see that the lists contain the needed data.

But I need to join the two lists together using a Linq query to get the result set that I need:

```
var historicalYears = (from mc in modCurricula
 join cy in cYear on mc.GroupId equals cy.GroupId
 where cy.CYear == 1810
 select mc.ModId).ToList();
```

However, when I do this, I get a list of 20 rows but each row is just the same data, like this:

```
 20384 | 04722811
 20384 | 04722811
 20384 | 04722811
 // etc...
```

So I tried joining the actual entity framework DbSet objects like this:

```
var historicalYears = (from mc in _context.ModCurricula
  join cy in _context.CYear on mc.GroupId equals cy.GroupId
  where cy.CYear == 1810
  select mc.ModId).ToList();
```

And it works!  I get the results I need, not just a list of duplicates.

Is there a reason why I'm getting duplicates using the first Linq query?

Thanks!

Comment: "only containing the first row both lists" - can you re-write that clearer? Your second example doesn't include the `Where` filters you used when creating the lists, so it isn't the same.

Comment: @NetMage That is rather vague.  Sorry about that.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Did you add the `Where` filters to your `DbSet` test? Is `ModId` == `20384 | 04722811` or does that represent something else?

Comment: @NetMage No I didn't add any filters or queries to the DbSet.  It's just data straight from the database. 20384 | 04722811 is the first row I get back from the join...or should be the first row.  In the case of my problem, every row returned is 20384 | 04722811.

Comment: But the queries are different. The last query doesn't have `c.Discriminator == 'C'` and a different filter on `ProductionStatus`. You should at least compare the same conditions.

Comment: @GertArnold I see what you mean.  Thanks for pointing that out.